# FuelSDK - Java - How to get the Subscriber List

Tags: dataextensions, fuel-sdk, java, subscriber

In the Java FuelSDK, how can I get a list of the email address mapped to the subscriber id now being passed for conversion?

If I can't do this in FuelSDK, how can I do it with another API?

Can I get it by reading a data extension? If so which and what column maps to the subscriber id?